# Filter spam and inappropriate content

Tags: spam-prevention

in a web application how is spam and inappropriate content filtered ... spam probably captcha and what abt inappropriate content, vulgarities etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With inappropriate content, you need to have a reference list of words you don't want to see. You can then flag / filter content based on your list. You can add to the list over time with words and phrases that have "got through".

As with all solutions, if you prevent people putting the word "hello", then they will inevitably start putting "h e l l o" or "hell0" or other variations, which are harder to detect.

The best way to catch them all is to supply a "flag inappropriate content" flag so humans can notify you of anything offensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a service such as [Aksimet](http://akismet.com/).